# Issue Running Artisan Command via Cronjob

Tags: laravel-4, cron

I'm having a bit of a nightmare getting a crontab/cronjob to run an Artisan command.

I have another Artisan command running via cronjob no problems but this second command won't run.

Firstly, when I do 'crontab -e' and edit the file to contain:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/php  /home/purple/public_html/artisan feeds:send
```

The cronjob doesn't run at all.

If I go to cPanel and add the cronjob there, it runs but I receive the following error:

```
open(public/downloads/feeds/events.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The thing is the file exists and the directories have the correct permissions. If I run the command when logged in via SSH as root or the user purple (php artisan feeds:send) the command runs flawlessly and completes its tasks no problem.

If in cPanel, I edit the cronjob to use:

```
0 0 * * * php  /home/purple/public_html/artisan feeds:send
```

I receive the following error:

```
 There are no commands defined in the "feeds" namespace.
```

The funny thing is that my other command is registered in the crontab file and works and has no reference in cPanel at all.

Any help would be much appreciated. Just for brevity I have included the command and model that the command uses.

Feed.php Model:

http://laravel.io/bin/1e2n

DataFeedController.php Controller:

http://laravel.io/bin/6x0E

SendFeeds.php Command:

http://laravel.io/bin/BW3d

start/artisan.php:

http://laravel.io/bin/2xV3

FeedInterface.php Interface:

http://laravel.io/bin/LxnO

As you can see there is a GetRates command, which works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it looks like I had to cd in to the script directory first before running the command, which now after working it out it makes sense. Easy when you know how eh!

```
* * * * * cd /home/purple/public_html/ && /usr/local/bin/php artisan feeds:send
```