# How can I run a seeder from a cronjob in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-seeding, laravel-jobs

I need to run a seeder what it takes a time to execute (like five minutes). But i set it in my crontab as:

```
0 0 * * * php /var/www/.../api/artisan db:seed --class=ApiPlayerStatisticsSeeder
```

And it does not run by itself. Looks like it need an user to execute. So, how i can run this seeder in background?

I tried making a comand and run in backgruound like a task in kernel file (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands), but it doesn't work either.

Comment: You have to cd into your app's directory && call the correct path of php followed by the artisan command. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785261/issue-running-artisan-command-via-cronjob). See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @LucasArbex, but it does not matter, because i executing the artisan file of the project, with "php /var/www/.../api/artisan".

Comment: Seems like an odd path to artisan to me. But just try cd into your app's directory, and then run the artisan command to see if the works... like I've mentioned in my answer..

Answer (score 1):

I use the laravel command scheduling on a daily basis. ill barebones how I insert a command to the schedule

```
$schedule->exec('php artisan command:here --flags 4434 --params 32')
    ->weeklyOn(3,'9:30');
```

the command:here is just whatever command you have written to complete your task. Same goes with 'flags' or 'params' if you dont need them or dont set them up then dont use them.

weeklyOn can be changed to hourly() everyfiveminutes(), monthly(), quarterly, etc please check the docs for the syntax

Answer (score 0):

On your cronjob, first cd into your app's directory and then call the artisan command. Like so:

```
0 0 * * * cd /path/to/app && php artisan db:seed --class=ApiPlayerStatisticsSeeder
```

Let me know if it worked.